# way to test stripe recurring failed payment

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions, stripe

Whenever recurring payment failed due to change in card number, card expiring, cancellation of credit card, or the card issuer not recognising the payment. I have to sent notification to user. Stripe have inbuilt functionality to sent notification but does not have way to customize the message sent to user.

I have to sent that message through civicrm.

CiviCRM already have functionality to handle 'invoice.payment_failed' event type which change status to 'Failed'. On top of that i have to send email notification to user.

Main question is, how do i generate testing scenario through CiviCRM to receive 'payment_failed' notification.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use unit test to check Failed recurring from stripe extension. It does cover most of the test for IPN.

You can find more details about the unit test [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/blob/master/tests/phpunit/CRM/Stripe/IpnTest.php#L144).

HTH

Pradeep